# Overriding any parameter in io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema throws exception

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-3.0

I have this open API annotation

```
    @GET
    @Operation(method = "Get orders", description = "GetOrdersRoute",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "batchSize", required = true,
                            schema = @Schema(type = "")),
                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "fromDate", required = true),
                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "filter", required = true)},
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(description = "The order",
                            content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                                    schema = @Schema(implementation = OrderDto.class)))})
    @Override
    public String handle(@Parameter(hidden = true) Request request, @Parameter(hidden = true) Response response) {
        return api.exec();
    }
```

It works. But when I add to `@Parameter` to `@Schema` any value like `schema = @Schema(type = "integer"))` I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.isCreatable(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

In other words:  `@Schema(type = ""))` works fine but  `@Schema(type = "integer"))` doesn't work.

And not only `type` parameter in `@Schema` annotation. Any override parameter in  `@Schema` annotation throws this exception.

But `@Schema` in `@ApiResponse` works fine with any override parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue today when using

```
@ApiResponse(
    responseCode = "200", 
    content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = MyDto.class)), 
    description = "Returns MyDto.")
```

with `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema` from `swagger 2.1.9`.

After trying different swagger versions (which were producing other errors in my setup), it worked when downgrading to `swagger 2.0.10`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `@Schema(type = "integer")` by `@Schema(implementation = Integer.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Add this Dependency

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
 </dependency>
```